# Lazy load at the product reviews section in magento 2

Tags: product, product-view, review, product-review, lazyload

I need to add lazy load feature on the product reviews tab instead of pagination if my product has more than 10 reviews.

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Did you get a solution?